# how to use ngx-permission module in routing for restricting particular components to particular users in angular5

Tags: angular

When I'm trying to use ngx-permission module it will give some errors in the console. This is the error I'm getting:

> Report1Component.html:78 ERROR TypeError: rxjs.merge is not a function
>       at NgxPermissionsDirective.validateExceptOnlyPermissions (ngx-permissions.umd.js:632)
>       at NgxPermissionsDirective.ngOnInit (ngx-permissions.umd.js:611)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12369)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (Report1Component.html:93)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)

Comment: Maybe first show your code and describe the configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct compatible version

```
npm install ngx-permissions@4.1 --save
```

`ngx-permission@5.0` version is compatible with Angular 6

`ngx-permission@4.1` version is compatible with Angular 5